# Identifying the duplicate occurrences of a combination and assign count to 1

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

I need a help with my SQL code to identify the duplicate sequence occurrence. Say, for example my table structure is like this:

```
Name   E_Date Maker    Status
----   ------ -----    ------
John   Apr-6  Apple    Success
Peter  Apr-6  Apple    Success
John   Apr-6  Apple    Success
Peter  Apr-7  Samsung  Success
John   Apr-6  Samsung  Success
John   Apr-6  Apple    Failure
Peter  Apr-6  Apple    Success
John   Apr-6  Apple    Success
```

So the above record have 4 columns / dimensions and you can see John Apr-6 Apple Success has three occurrences. My SQL code should count this and assign rec_cnt = 3 and dup_cnt = 1

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  I'm curious, why is the dup count 1 and not 2 (or simply `dup_cnt = rec_cnt - 1`)?  Also, why does your table not have a name?  Or how are we supposed to write queries against your anonymous table.  (You're not the first to forget that tables have names; I gave your data column names.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
SELECT Name, E_Date, Maker, Status, COUNT(*) AS Rec_Cnt
  FROM AnonymousTable
 GROUP BY Name, E_Date, Maker, Status
```

Until you identify how the `dup_cnt` is produced, I'm not going to attempt to evaluate that, either.

I also observe that your table has no primary key, which is generally a bad idea.  You should ensure that there is some way of preventing duplicate entries in a table.  If worst comes to worst, you add one of the ubiquitous ID columns, but if there's an alternative, you should use that in preference.